# tableof package erases citations

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, biber

Somehow using `\tableof` keeps *biblatex* from detecting cites.

Can anyone confirm the problem, and, even better, provide a solution?

In the example below, running *pdflatex* and *biber* produces `Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0`

If you comment the line with `\tableof`, it finds the citation: `Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0`

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[toc=bibliographynumbered, ngerman]{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @Book{Graupe.1996,
      author   = {Friedrich Graupe},
      title    = {250 Super Suppen},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tableof}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \toftagthis{test}
    \section{abc}

    \tableof{test} % comment out and biber works

    \cite{Graupe.1996}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tableof` is leaking!

`biblatex` writes some internal stuff to `.toc` files to stop the table of contents from messing up the citation order. In a normal document this is no big deal: The `.toc` file is read in a group, so those internal commands only affect the printed table of contents.

`\tableof` on the other hand, does not group the entire file when it is read. Instead `tableof` adds a few commands of its own to the `.toc` file that take care of the grouping. Unfortunately, `biblatex` has already written its internal commands into the `.toc` file, before `tableof` does so, so `biblatex`'s commands are outside the `tableof` group.

You can obtain the desired output in the MWE if you add curly braces around `\tableof`, but I don't know if that has other consequences. Maybe you could get in touch with the `tableof` developer and ask them if it would be possible to always group `\tableof`.

```
\documentclass[toc=bibliographynumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tableof}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \toftagthis{test}
  \section{abc}
  {\tableof{test}}
  \cite{sigfridsson}

  \toftagthis{rest}
  \section{xyz}
  {\tableof{rest}}
  \cite{worman}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I would never have found this myself. It works in my larger document with no side effects so far.

I will contact the author, maybe he/she can fix this in the packe itself.